# Error [create table session (year varchar(255) for bit data not null, session varchar(255)

Tags: hibernate, jpa, servlets, glassfish

Here is the error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'for bit data
>   not null, session varchar(255) not null, endingDate date, startingD'
>   at line 1

This is the class cauing the error: 
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "session")
    public class Session implements Serializable {
        @Id
        private String session;
        @Id
        private Year year;

```
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    @Nullable
    private Date startingDate;

    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    @Nullable
    private Date endingDate;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Utilisateur.class)
    @Nullable
    private Utilisateur utilisateur;

    public Session() {

    }

    public String getSession() {
        return session;
    }

    public void setSession(String session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public Year getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Year year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public Date getStartingDate() {
        return startingDate;
    }

    public void setStartingDate(Date startingDate) {
        this.startingDate = startingDate;
    }

    public Date getEndingDate() {
        return endingDate;
    }

    public void setEndingDate(Date endingDate) {
        this.endingDate = endingDate;
    }

    public Utilisateur getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }
}
```